# Facter ignoring variables at runtime

Tags: variables, puppet

I have a Facter custom fact for use in Puppet that should generate a list of specific information, but it doesn't always work correctly, even on servers running the exact same versions of ruby, facter, puppet, and mysql. The code is below:

```
#backends.rb
puts "Backends retrieval"
if Facter.value('demainversion') == '2'
  dbasename = Facter.value('dbasename')
  if dbasename == ''
    dbasename = 'database'
  end
  mysqlcmd = "mysql -uUser -pPassword #{dbasename} --skip_column_names -e "
  if Facter.value('clustered')
    dbasename = Facter.value('dbasename')
    mysqlcmd = "mysql -uUser -pPassword -hclustered-host #{dbasename} --skip_column_names -e "
  end
  puts mysqlcmd
  clients = Facter.value('databases').split(', ')
  if clients != ''
    clients.each do |client|
      count = 0
      client_id =
      res =
      backends = ""
      facter_name = "#{client.gsub(' ','_')}_backends"
      Facter.add("#{facter_name}") do
        setcode do
          puts "#{client} listing"
          client_id = %x[#{mysqlcmd}"SELECT id FROM UserGroup WHERE groupName='#{client.strip}'"].strip
          puts "#{client_id} listing"
          puts backends
          res = %x[#{mysqlcmd}"SELECT sourceMachine,sourceUser FROM GrabberJob WHERE clientGroup_id=#{client_id.strip}"].strip
          res.each do |row|
            machine = row.split(' ')[0]
            login = row.split(' ')[1]
            val = login.gsub('admin','')
            if count == 0
              backends << machine.strip << "(" << val << ")"
            else
              backends << ", " << machine.strip << "(" << val << ")"
            end
            count += 1
          end
          backends.strip
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When puppet (or irb) runs this it may (or may not) return ...

> ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 1: No database selected

... but if the server throws the error it will continue to exhibit the problem.  I know that the dbasename variable is set correctly, courtesy of the puts statements used for debugging, but the variable is ignored when the mysql commands are actually run.

I have also tried adding a `USE #{dbasename};` statement to the client_id and res commands to no avail. Any suggestions on what I could do to make it work consistently would be most appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered **not** screen-scraping output of the `mysql` CLI but use a Ruby binding instead?

Comment: I have considered using it and will probably end up doing it but I am interested in finding a workable solution as it may not just be helpful in this case but others as well. I have basically taken what was written for this job previously by my predecessor and trying to add to it at the moment. Ruby is not my forte.

Comment: Have you tried running the same `mysql` commands from a shell on a machine that has this problem?